# Сайт считает вопрос спамом

Tags: дефект, поддержка

[Отправка smtp почты с камер видеонаблюдения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/777553/178988)

тут должен был быть вопрос, но этот "умный сайт" считает его спамом, поэтому ловите изображение, и догадывайтесь сами что там за вопрос

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: О таких приколах лучше [связываться со Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: Не видна нижняя часть вопроса. Нет ли у вас там ещё ссылок или адреса электропочты?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, возможно повлияло наличие нескольких строк с `smtp.mail.ru`

Comment: Такое ощущение что это нам нужен ваш вопрос, а не вам... Что это за формулировка: *"поэтому ловите изображение, и догадывайтесь сами что там за вопрос?"*

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, полный текст вопроса, который вы хотели задать в этот вопрос на Мете (прямо в тело, ниже текущего вопроса).

Comment: _"Такое ощущение что это нам нужен ваш вопрос, а не вам... Что это за формулировка"_   Да потому что я писал это 20 минут, там были настройки smtp сервера. А кто–то решил, что настройки smtp  сервера являются спамом. Ну и на зачем такой крутой сайт нужен. Где даже вопрос не можешь опубликовать.

Comment: @Low-voltagesystemsengineer Повторюсь, пожалуйста, добавьте ваш вопрос в данный вопрос на Мете, чтобы мы могли посмотреть, что именно пошло не так.

Comment: @Low-voltagesystemsengineer Повторюсь, пожалуйста, добавьте ваш вопрос в данный вопрос на Мете, чтобы мы могли посмотреть, что именно пошло не так.